# How to determine the tag to Downgrade flutter from 2.0? Cannot build project anymore

Tags: flutter

I just updated my flutter and my project is not building anymore. I am getting the following error

> Because project depends on progress_hud >=0.1.1 which requires SDK
>   version >=1.23.0 <2.0.0, version solving failed.
>       pub upgrade failed (1)

Now I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468321/how-to-downgrade-flutter-sdk-dart-1-x) link here which states that I should checkout that specific Tag. How do I know which Tag is associated with which branch ? Essentially I would like anything closer less than 2.0. Preferably 1.9 or something like that. How do I determine which tag that is?

Comment: You can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63304250/2025766 and use the flutter downgrade command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't downgrade your Dart version, there is an issue with that package, it doesn't have the constraints updated : https://github.com/rcpassos/progress_hud/blob/master/pubspec.yaml

As you can see these constraints:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=1.23.0 <2.0.0"
```

Doesn't allow to build your app, you have two options:

1. wait for the owner to update the constraints
2. Use a fork from another user with the constraints updated, like
   this:

Instead of this :

```
dependencies:
  progress_hud: ^1.0.0
```

Use this:

```
dependencies:
  progress_hud:
    git: https://github.com/LampeMW/progress_hud/
```

Comment: so basically if we supply a url then it checks for the most compatible one ?

Comment: If you use a git url it will use the code from that repository which has the constraints updated.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. also what happens if we declare a package like this `build_runner:` instead of `build_runner:^0.8.0` ? I had to get rid of the version from build_runner to continue building my project

Comment: it will use the last version : https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/build_runner#-changelog-tab-

Answer (score 0):

Don't Downgrade Flutter. Instead add following tags in
pubspec.yaml

```
dependency_overrides:
  shared_preferences: ">=0.5.12+4"
```

place your problematic packages lower versions.