# How to downgrade your flutter SDK version?

Tags: flutter

My current Dart SDK Version is 2.1.2-dev.0.0.flutter-0a7dcf17eb.
However i need to use a flutter text recognition Dependency that requires SDK version >=1.23.0 <2.0.0

How can I downgrade my version?

Comment: check this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14230

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to downgrade Flutter SDK (Dart 1.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468321/how-to-downgrade-flutter-sdk-dart-1-x)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the Flutter install directory execute

```
git checkout v1.2.2
```

Now run

```
flutter doctor
```

Comment: my current version is Flutter 1.2.1 so wont this be upgrading...
How do i find out which version of flutter supports dart  >=1.23.0 <2.0.0

Comment: checked out to v1.0.0

Answer (score 7):

You can just go from a version to another using the new commands

- `flutter downgrade` -> go to the previous
- `flutter upgrade` -> update to the new one

Comment: I would like to go to the flutter version that was previously installed. I think it is 1.22.4. Please help me out here. Thank you.

Comment: @SemiDeveloper is flutter downgrade working for you?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a specific version of Flutter that you want to switch to (e.g. a previous stable version), you can use the `flutter version` command:

First find the version you wish to switch to here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases

Then, use `flutter version` command:

```
 flutter version v1.9.1+hotfix.3
```

To pin Flutter package to a specific version, specify Flutter version explicitly in the pubspec.yaml file environment section:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.19.0 <3.0.0'
  flutter: ^0.1.2
```

Comment: The new command is:

```
Warning: "flutter version" will leave the SDK in a detached HEAD state.
If you are using the command to return to a previously installed SDK version consider using the "flutter downgrade" command instead.
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to run one command

```
flutter version
```

Above command shows you list of flutter version after that you can choose any version from that list. Using for example `flutter version v1.9.1+hotfix.6`

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56645736/13521429),

In the Flutter install directory execute

```
git checkout <version number>
```

Eg: `git checkout 3.13.7`, notice there is no 'v' prefix in front of version number instead just write the version directly

Now run

```
flutter doctor
```