# Flutter app build is failing, need help to resolve dependencies

Tags: android, dart, flutter, open-source

I am starting with flutter development and I thought that starting with opensource apps will be a good idea.
I am trying to build this app : [FlutterCinematic](https://github.com/aaronoe/FlutterCinematic)

and I am getting the following error:-

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.9.4.flutter-f9ebf21297.

Because movies_flutter depends on scoped_model >=0.1.1 <0.3.0 which requires SDK version <2.0.0, version solving failed.

pub upgrade failed (1)
```

I tried running `flutter upgrade` but it was not helpful.
Any leads are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in `pubspec.yaml` `dependencies:`

```
scoped_model: ">=0.1.1 <0.3.0"
```

to

```
scoped_model: ^1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your log indicates that your SDK is 2.1.0 and your dependencies requires an SDK less than 2.0.0. If you're keen on running this app you should downgrade your SDK, take a look at this post : [How to downgrade Flutter SDK (Dart 1.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468321/how-to-downgrade-flutter-sdk-dart-1-x) as it explains the downgrading process in general and provides an example of a specific case `Dart SDK 1.9.0`