# Specify Flutter version during upgrade

Tags: flutter

I work on a Flutter application on two different PC's and would like the Flutter version to be the same for both. I am on the `dev` channel and when I do a `flutter upgrade` it ugrades to the latest version in that channel.

Two days ago I did a `flutter upgrade` on one PC and it went to version `1.2.2`. Today on my other PC I did a `flutter upgrade 1.2.2` but it went to version `1.3.2` instead.

Is there a way for me to specify the flutter version when upgrading?

Comment: You can check this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468321/how-to-downgrade-flutter-sdk-dart-1-x. The accepted answer has specified what command to use.

Answer (score 29):

This is not yet supported.
There is an open issue for that https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14230

Currently you can use Git commands to get a specific version

```
$ cd flutter
$ # git checkout [branch, tag or commit hash]
$ git checkout v1.2.2
```

**UPDATE : But after version 1.17.0 tag naming convention has been changed so,**

```
$ cd flutter
$ # git checkout [branch, tag or commit hash]
$ git checkout 3.0.0
```

**Update**

`flutter downgrade <version>` is now supported.

The *available versions* can be be found in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tags

Comment: This is possible now with `flutter version`.

In the console do `flutter version` to list the versions available.

Then choose a version to switch to: `flutter version v1.2.1`

Comment: Sadly, in the Beta channel's (with Flutter 1.23.x, the `version` command seems to be deprecated: https://github.com/flutter/website/issues/4935

Comment: Updated answer with `flutter downgrade` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56127174/3758439

Comment: make sure you run **flutter doctor** after **flutter downgrade <version>**

Comment: Please use short method  to update your flutter version directly to particular one buy following command :
flutter version <version_no>

Comment: I used version 2.10.3 and the problem was solved. Every time use stable version

Comment: The use of "downgrade" is incorrect. The downgrade command only downgrades to the previous stable, it does not go to a specific version.

Comment: `which flutter` gives me **/Users/me/development/flutter/bin/flutter**, and then if I `cd /Users/me/development/flutter` I can `git checkout 3.13.2`. :)

If you get **error: pathspec 'v3.13.2' did not match any file(s) known to git**, you might need to specify the version without the leading 'v'