# decoding json web token flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to decode my JWT token in my flutter project when i installed it im my  pubspec.yaml file

this error appears

> ```
> The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.9.4.flutter-f9ebf21297.
>
> Because idb depends on jwt any which requires SDK version <2.0.0, version solving failed.
>
> pub get failed (1)
> exit code 1
> ```

and this my pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.15.7
  jwt: ^0.1.4
```

Comment: The error message clearly says its a version issue. You'll have change the version of flutter to match the libraries dependency or vice versa

Comment: i know but do i have to downgrade or upgrade?

Comment: You'll need Dart below version 2 for that library to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]This is due to version issue. In this [link](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/jwt), it clearly says **DART 2 INCOMPATIBLE** for `jwt` package.

**EDIT:**
This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468321/how-to-downgrade-flutter-sdk-dart-1-x) answers how to downgrade.

Comment: Checkout the link in the answer. Another question has been asked and answered on how to do this