# Android studio giving errors in setting up existing Google Flutter project

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter, dart

The developer is trying to set up the environment the first time. Same code is getting set up for other developers without any issue. But only on this machine, he is getting issues.

**Dart version: 2.7.2
Flutter Version: 1.12.13+hotfix.9**

We tried doing **pub cache repair**
but it did not help

```
Compiler message:
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flushbar-1.9.1/lib/flushbar_route.dart:273:8: Error: The method 'FlushbarRoute.install' has more required arguments than those of overridden method 'OverlayRoute.install'.
  void install(OverlayEntry insertionPoint) {
       ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart:41:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('install').
  void install() {
       ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dio-2.2.2/lib/src/dio_http_headers.dart:55:8: Error: The method 'DioHttpHeaders.add' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'HttpHeaders.add'.
  void add(String name, value) {
       ^
org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/_http/http.dart:694:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('add').
  void add(String name, Object value,
       ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dio-2.2.2/lib/src/dio_http_headers.dart:70:8: Error: The method 'DioHttpHeaders.set' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'HttpHeaders.set'.
  void set(String name, Object value) {
       ^
org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/_http/http.dart:703:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('set').
  void set(String name, Object value,
       ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_datetime_picker-1.2.8/lib/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart:14:9: Error: The superclass, 'Diagnosticable', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
  const DatePickerTheme({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flushbar-1.9.1/lib/flushbar_route.dart:281:18: Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
    super.install(insertionPoint);
                 ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie-0.9.8+1/lib/src/chewie_player.dart:126:31: Error: No named parameter with the name 'isInitialRoute'.
      settings: RouteSettings(isInitialRoute: false),
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart:458:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const RouteSettings({
```

Flutter doctor -v output

```
Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.900], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.17.4 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 1ad9baa8b9 (7 days ago), 2020-06-17 14:41:16 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 46.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
[√] VS Code (version 1.46.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.11.0
[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • vivo 1724 • 5d79ce31 • android-arm64 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27)
• No issues found!
```

Comment: What is the output of `flutter doctor -v` ?
In Android Studio version 4.0 there were plugin changes which requires flutter and dart plugins to be updated. Try checking for updates. If everything else is alright try `flutter clean` .

Comment: I had a similar problem with Flushbar, upgrade flutter by running `flutter upgrade` and then clean the project by `flutter clean`. The error should disappear then.

Comment: @dev-aentgs updated output of flutter doctor -v

Comment: Tried flutter upgrade and flutter clean but getting same error

Comment: @sandeep file menu -> invalidate caches and restart

Comment: Tried this too.. But no luck

Comment: oh. One more try, check version of packages in `pubspec.yaml` and update them if any are outdated @sandeep

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. I have mentioned the solution in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was mismatch between packages and flutter version. So after downgrading the flutter the problem is resolved.

**References:**

[How to downgrade Flutter SDK (Dart 1.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468321/how-to-downgrade-flutter-sdk-dart-1-x)

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14230