# Flutter Downgrade from Version 2.0.0 (version solving failed)

Tags: flutter

Today Flutter 2.0.0 was released. After I installed it, I got some version solving problems:

```
Because foo depends on flutter_localizations any from sdk which depends on intl 0.17.0, intl 0.17.0 is required.
So, because foodepends on intl ^0.16.1, version solving failed. 
Running "flutter pub get" in foo...                              
pub get failed (1; So, because foo depends on intl ^0.16.1, version solving failed.)
```

If I set `intl` to the newest version I get:

```
Because dash_chat >=1.0.10 depends on intl ^0.16.0 and foo depends on intl ^0.17.0, dash_chat >=1.0.10 is forbidden.
So, because foo depends on dash_chat ^1.1.15, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in foo...                              
pub get failed (1; So, because foo depends on dash_chat ^1.1.15, version solving failed.)
```

But DashChat 1.1.15 is the latest version.

I think the only way to solve this at the moment is to downgrade flutter.
I tried `flutter version v1.22.6` and `flutter downgrade`, but none if these works:

```
There is no previously recorded version for channel "stable".
```

So how can I downgrade to to Flutter 1.22.6 for example?

Comment: this might help: [version change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468321/how-to-downgrade-flutter-sdk-dart-1-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add that to `pubspec.yaml`

```
 dependency_overrides:
      intl: 0.17.0-nullsafety.2
```

And delete `intl: 0.17.0` from dependencies part of `pubspec.yaml`. I think you do not need to downgrade Flutter with this.

Answer (score 2):

In your situation you got 2 options:

- Fork the package `dash_chat` to upgrade its `intl` dependency to the most recent one, then instead of getting it from pub fetch the package from your git repository:

```yaml
dash_chat:
   git:
     path: https://my_git_path.com
     ref: master
```

- Or as you have said you can revert to a previous version of Flutter. If `flutter downgrade` doesn't work for you, you can still download a previous releases from the [official flutter page](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases) and replace your local Flutter SDK by the one you downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

1. Switch to channel then downgrade specific ver you want. For example

   `flutter channel stable` then
   `flutter downgrade 1.22.6`
2. Checkout specific branch of flutter
   `git checkout flutter-1.27-candidate.9`

Remember to reload code editor & run `flutter clean` to avoid unexpected errors.

Comment: The first approach does not not work: `There is no previously recorded version for channel "stable".`

Comment: Opps my mistake. It's not supported in release ver or channel stable. Can you try to switch to channel dev then downgrade. I edited my answer.

Comment: I still get the same error: `There is no previously recorded version for channel "dev".`

Answer (score 0):

For new readers that looking to downgrade the flutter version 3.0.5 stable to any other version all you have to do is :
go to "/snap/flutter/common/flutter"
run "git checkout 'the version you want to switch to'"
run "flutter --version "