# How to downgrade flutter version

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I updated my flutter version by `flutter upgrade --force` command and now my project doesn't compile
is there is a way to downgrade to old version (i dont know my old version number)

please help me because this is my graduation project

Comment: i can upload it in github to see and help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to downgrade Flutter SDK (Dart 1.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468321/how-to-downgrade-flutter-sdk-dart-1-x)

Answer (score 27):

If you're seeing the message:

`There is no previously recorded version for channel "stable".`

Navigate to your Flutter installation folder and run `git checkout flutter_version`

If you're using snap on Linux and want to downgrade to 1.22.6:

```
cd $HOME/$USER/snap/flutter/common/flutter
git checkout 1.22.6
flutter --version
```

Comment: On macOS just went to ~/flutter, entered git checkout 2.0.6 and it worked :)

Answer (score 12):

For change the Flutter sdk version use this command:
For upgrade the latest version:

flutter upgrade  1.20.0   //version number

For decrease the Flutter sdk version:

flutter downgrade 1.18.0 // version number

And for check the version which you Currently used:

flutter --version

Answer (score 9):

You need go to flutter sdk folder and run git command checkout your version

get flutter sdk path on android studio:

```
File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Flutter -> FLutter SDK path
```

[image]

Change flutter channel if you want

```
flutter channel <branch> (example: flutter channel dev or flutter channel stable)
```

Change Flutter version:

```
git checkout <version> (example: git checkout 2.0.3)
```

after: `flutter doctor -v`

**hope to help some body**

Answer (score 8):

```
flutter downgrade versionnumber
```

Eg : `flutter downgrade 1.25.0`

Answer (score 3):

Changing the Flutter version is like changing git branch.

if you want to change the channel use

```
flutter channel <branch> (example: flutter channel dev or flutter channel stable)
```

There are four flutter Channels

> 1). stable 2). dev 3). beta 4). master

You can further study about these channels from [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels)

```
flutter downgrade <version>
```

You can see versions from [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tags)

After completion, run  flutter doctor, and Flutter will take care of downloading/compiling everything required to run this version.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best method to switch flutter versions

### First:

Check the **Flutter versions** that you want and in what **Channel**
from here https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos

### Second:

on your terminal just type
1- switch to the channel that contains your version

```
flutter channel stable
```

2- downgrade using this

```
flutter downgrade v2.10.5
```

This is working for me every time

Answer (score 1):

`flutter version` is now deprecated. `flutter downgrade <version-no>` will do the trick ! After this run `flutter doctor`. It will take care of the rest.

Comment: So, this worked for me but sort of softly locked up. I couldn't stop the process or run anything, even after a half hour. I restarted Android Studio and ran `flutter doctor` and the process completed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple question,

1- you have to access the directory where your flutter is installed by terminal. 
 ex: cd C:\src\flutter  
2 - then, you write the command git checkout (number of version). 
3 - flutter --version.

It's similar with the guy above, but the difference is that i was trying to
install downloading the file on the link for sdk installations, but it didn't work.
So, i followed these steps and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was downloading the version directly from [Flutter SDK's website](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos) and replacing the old flutter folder from /Users/NAME/flutter/ with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter downgrade versionnumber
```

and then

```
flutter doctor -v
```

works!

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?