# No named parameter with the name 'resizeToAvoidBottomPadding'

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to run my app on VSCode but I get this error:
[image]

I've tried to update flutter version/pubspec packages version/`flutter clean`/delete the build folder and run again. But nothing seems to work.

this is my `pubspec.yaml`
add_2_calendar: ^2.0.1

```
  add_2_calendar: ^2.0.1
  camera: ^0.7.0+2
  charts_flutter: ^0.10.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  device_calendar: ^3.1.0
  dio: ^3.0.10
  dio_http_cache: ^0.2.9
  expandable: ^5.0.1
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  firebase_database: ^6.0.0
  firebase_messaging: ^8.0.0-dev.15
  fl_chart: ^0.35.0
  flick_video_player: ^0.1.1
  flutter_email_sender: ^5.0.0
  flutter_form_builder: ^6.0.0-nullsafety.1
  flutter_icons: ^1.1.0
  flutter_linkify: ^5.0.0
  flutter_paginator: ^0.0.6
  flutter_svg: ^0.19.3
  flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.5.0+3
  fluttericon: ^2.0.0
  gallery_saver: ^2.0.1
  geolocator: ^6.2.1
  get_it: ^6.0.0
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  image_picker: ^0.6.2+3
  intl: ^0.17.0
  mailer: ^5.0.0
  overlay_support: ^1.0.5
  path_provider: ^1.6.11
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
  provider: ^4.0.5
  splashscreen: ^1.2.0
  timeline_tile: ^2.0.0
  url_launcher: ^5.5.0
  video_player: ^0.10.12+2
  weather_icons: ^2.0.2
  webview_flutter: ^1.0.7
```

`flutter --version`

[image]

`flutter doctor`

[image]

Comment: rename `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` to `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` in your `Scaffold` resizeToAvoidBottomPadding is deprecated in favor of inset one

Comment: I searched with vsCode for <code>resizeToAvoidBottomPadding</code> but it didn't find anything.

Comment: sorry I wasnt paing enough attention, seems like the problem in `chewie` package that is v 0.10.4 and not null safe yet, you shure this is full list of pubspec.yaml file? No `chewie: ^0.10.4` there?

Comment: I forgot to add `add_2_calendar: ^2.0.1` but I checked and no `chewie`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get this is that you use [flutter_widget_from_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widget_from_html), that has no *null safe* version yet, this package depends on old version of [chewie](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie) (v0.10.4), that uses deprecated property of Scaffold `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding`.

What you can do is to downgrade  your Flutter SDK to pre null-safety version, or rewrite your code without using `flutter_widget_from_html` package in favor for example `chewie`, that already has null safety widget.

You can check more info about migrating to *null safety* [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide).

If you are willing to downgrade your SDK to pre-null safety you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56127174/13701546) answer.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. And if it works I'll mark this as the correct answer

Comment: @t3nsa wait a bit, I just found that they have beta null safety, change version to `flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.6.0` in your pubspec.yaml, run `flutter pub get` and try again.

Comment: it says that version 0.6.0 doesn't exist

Comment: @t3nsa https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widget_from_html/versions/0.6.0-rc.2021031201 try `flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.6.0-rc.2021031201`

Comment: I've tried but I get error that version solving failed and I've tried to change the version but couldn't get it to work

Comment: I went to beta by mistake and after that I changed back to stable and I got these errors that I mentioned in my question