# How do I roll back to Dart 2.10.4 with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

The recent change to Dart 2.12 (null safety change) broke my flutter project.
How do I roll back to Dart 2.10.4?

Comment: here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468321/how-to-downgrade-flutter-sdk-dart-1-x

Comment: 2.12 acts according to the minSDK in pubspec.yaml.  If you want an older Dart, set the minSDK to a value around 2.10 or so.