# How to downgrade dart back to dart 1.x in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I accidentally upgraded dart and flutter to the newest version but my code don't support null safety yet. Now I want to downgrade back to dart 1.x.

I tried `flutter downgrade v1.2.1` but nothing changed. How can I downgrade back to dart 1.x?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to downgrade Flutter SDK (Dart 1.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468321/how-to-downgrade-flutter-sdk-dart-1-x)

Comment: Yes I followed the top answer and used the command flutter downgrade v1.2.1 but its still with null safety

Comment: Did you run flutter doctor after downgrading the dart

Comment: check flutter fvm https://fvm.app/

Comment: I tried it again. Now I get the error ' There is no previously recorded version for channel "stable". ' when I run flutter downgrade v1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade flutter version by following below sequence.

1. type 'flutter downgrade 1.22.6'
2. Just type and command.
   'flutter verion'

After 1,2 steps, you can see downgrading processing.

Answer (score 0):

there is a tool that helps to manage different versions of flutter [FVM](https://fvm.app/)
or you can use

`flutter downgrade <version>` (example: `flutter downgrade v1.2.1`)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to downgrade flutter one the way which I use is to download the required SDK, unzip the folder and replace the existing **flutter** folder with the downloaded one.

Then restart the editor and you will the version you wanted.

Here are links for the Flutter SDK Release:

**Windows**
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases

**MacOS**
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos