# How to use old version of Flutter and Dart

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm a new developer and I'm trying to work with an existing IOS application built with Flutter. Some of the pubspec.yaml files show:

version 1.0.2+1
environment sdk ">=2.3.0 <3.0.0

And then various dependencies of other apps.

If I use the latest version of flutter, the application doesn't build. It needs to be built with flutter v1.0.0. But when I install that specific version, flutter pub get doesn't get the rest of the dependencies.

I'm guessing that I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

Please help!

Thank you,

Thomas

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468321/how-to-downgrade-flutter-sdk-dart-1-x