# Flutter - build failed in

Tags: flutter, flutter-run

run code after one year then face this issue
when flutter run command then command response error
how can remove these error
also run command flutter create -t app

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.3.3+1/lib/src/widgets/selectable.dart:407:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'InternalSelectableMathState' is missing implementations for these members:

- TextSelectionDelegate.copySelection
- TextSelectionDelegate.cutSelection
- TextSelectionDelegate.pasteText
- TextSelectionDelegate.selectAll
  Try to either
- provide an implementation,
- inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
- mark the class as abstract, or
- provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class InternalSelectableMathState extends State
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1034:8: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.copySelection' is defined here.
void copySelection(SelectionChangedCause cause);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1014:8: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.cutSelection' is defined here.
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             26.1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Well, I hate bringing you bad news, but Flutter received a LOT of updates. You might want to either

- Use an older version of Flutter (see: [THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468321/how-to-downgrade-flutter-sdk-dart-1-x))
- Refactor your code to adhere to the changes