# Failing to run Flutter app on a different machine

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I have been working on a flutter project for a while now, but I had to change the PC I am using for some reasons. the thing is that every time I try to run the app I get bunch of errors then the app crashes and the connection get lost. I tried to run the app from the old PC again and It worked fine.

This is the stack of errors I get before the crash:

> E/LB      (21021): fail to open file: No such file or directory
> I/m.example.test(21021): ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=92 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000
> D/DecorView: getWindowModeFromSystem  windowmode is 1
> I/flutter (21021): True
> E/AndroidRuntime(21021): FATAL EXCEPTION: flutter-worker-1
> E/AndroidRuntime(21021): Process: com.example.test1, PID: 21021
> E/AndroidRuntime(21021): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/tekartik/sqflite/LogLevel;
> E/AndroidRuntime(21021):    at com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin.onOpenDatabaseCall(SqflitePlugin.java:733)
> E/AndroidRuntime(21021):    at com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin.onMethodCall(SqflitePlugin.java:983)
> E/AndroidRuntime(21021):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:261)
> E/AndroidRuntime(21021):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
> E/AndroidRuntime(21021):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:321)
> E/AndroidRuntime(21021):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
> E/AndroidRuntime(21021):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$SerialTaskQueue.flush(DartMessenger.java:173)
> E/AndroidRuntime(21021):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$SerialTaskQueue.lambda$dispatch$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger$SerialTaskQueue(DartMessenger.java:163)
> E/AndroidRuntime(21021):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$SerialTaskQueue$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
> E/AndroidRuntime(21021):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> E/AndroidRuntime(21021):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> E/AndroidRuntime(21021):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
> E/AndroidRuntime(21021): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tekartik.sqflite.LogLevel" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~Jf92ML0d6XYgNbFc-Me8kg==/com.example.test1-i0I0QGqwfxD8m-Juiw5BfQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~Jf92ML0d6XYgNbFc-Me8kg==/com.example.test1-i0I0QGqwfxD8m-Juiw5BfQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~Jf92ML0d6XYgNbFc-Me8kg==/com.example.test1-i0I0QGqwfxD8m-Juiw5BfQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
> E/AndroidRuntime(21021):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
> E/AndroidRuntime(21021):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
> E/AndroidRuntime(21021):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
> E/AndroidRuntime(21021):    ... 12 more
> I/Process (21021): Sending signal. PID: 21021 SIG: 9
> Lost connection to device.

Anyone have any idea of what is going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have the same version of flutter as the computer you are using? You can [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468321/how-to-downgrade-flutter-sdk-dart-1-x) thread