# Flutter SDK is not selected in Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am using Windows 10 and Visual Studio code for Flutter development. It was working fine till I upgraded the VS code to the latest version of Flutter. Now I am not able to do anything on VS code as the SDK selection for flutter always shows up and I am not able to select those [image]

I tried to uninstall and install VS Code as well as its extensions multiple times but no help. Another observation is that when I click Cntrl + Shift + P, I am now able to see SDK option which was coming previously.
How can I select the Flutter SDK and avoid this issue
PS :- I am able to run in Android Studio so no issue with the system only for the VSCode Flutter Extension

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution to the problem. I just deleted the `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User` folder. It seems likesome kind of caching has happened which was causing this issue. Post this it started working fine. Thank you for all the people who has responded

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to do this manually. I have solved this problem before as [in the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56127174/13457125)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my issue is not related to the upgrading/downgrading of flutter. It is on VS Code where the SDK is not getting selected. The dropdown will come to autodetect SDK or select from the path as shown below, however I am not able to select any value from dropdown and it wont allow any other button press as well since it expects this dropdown to be selected first

Answer (score 1):

You can create `.vscode` folder if you don't have that kind of folder in your workspace.

Then you can create `settings.json` file and overwrite those paths to your **json** file.

```
{
   "dart.flutterSdkPath": "your_flutter_path",
   "dart.sdkPath": "your_dart_path"
}
```

Comment: Hello Nijat,
Thanks for the reply. I have tried this method. I guess the latest version of the VSCode does not create this folder - .vscode. Anyways I created those manually and made the following entry

Comment: It didn't work?

Comment: `{"dart.sdkPath": "E:\\software\\flutter\\bin\\cache\\dart-sdk\\",
 "dart.flutterSdkPath": "E:\\software\\flutter\\"}`
However it didn't help. At the bottom of VSCode I have see the Dart version selected. however it is like a javascript bug where the dropdown is always open. Is there any way I can clear all VS Code caches and reinstall. Even though I remove the installation folder, it has no impact. It is caches somewhere else because on reinstallation, I can still see the last projects worked on. If you know how to clear caches, please let me know