# iOS Simulator Opening But Not Connecting To Visual Studio Code

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator

Hello I Use MacOs Catalina(Mac mini (Late 2012))
I Recently Installed Flutter 2.10.5 and XCode Version 12.4 (12D4e)
And I Am When I Click Start IOS Simulator It Is Opeining IOS Simulator But Not Connecting And Showing
'Failed to launch iOS Simulator: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds'

And When I Run `flutter doctor -v`

```
   [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2026 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 3.10.5 on channel stable at /Users/subrahmanyamkarri/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 796c8ef792 (11 days ago), 2023-06-13 15:51:02 -0700
    • Engine revision 45f6e00911
    • Dart version 3.0.5
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/subrahmanyamkarri/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 12D4e
    ✗ Flutter requires Xcode 13 or higher.
      Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.79.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.66.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2026 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 114.0.5735.133

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I Expected The Project To Open In iOS Simulator But It Is Not Opening

Comment: can u run "flutter doctor -v" at your terminal?

Comment: [!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 12D4e
    ✗ Flutter requires Xcode 13 or higher.
      Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

Comment: edit in you question please

Answer (score 0):

OK you see your problem when you run `flutter doctor -v`. Just need to download newest XCode from App Store, or consider downgrade flutter version if you don't want to do that.

Reference: [How to downgrade Flutter SDK (Dart 1.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468321/how-to-downgrade-flutter-sdk-dart-1-x)